# How to generate an OpenAPI 2.0 file with NSwag?

Tags: swagger, openapi, nswag

I'm using NSwag and trying to convert an OpenAPI JSON document to version 2. This is my configuration:

```csharp
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
            services.AddControllers();

            services.AddOpenApiDocument(config =>
            {
                config.PostProcess = doc =>
                {
                    doc.SchemaType = NJsonSchema.SchemaType.Swagger2;
                }
            }
}
```

However, when I paste the generated OpenAPI file into Swagger Editor, it shows errors:

[image]

How to configure NSwag to generate a proper OpenAPI 2.0 file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To configure NSwag to output an OpenAPI 2.0 definition instead of OpenAPI 3.0, use `.AddSwaggerDocument(...)` instead of `.AddOpenAPIDocument(...)`. More info:

https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/wiki/AspNetCore-Middleware